# How do I package a Java application with resources including Java runtime for Debian

Tags: java, deployment, debian

I have a Java application that is ready to deploy. Since most of the users are on Linux (Debian), I would like to make them an installer (`.deb`) package that they can simply install.

I tried to package it using [Debreate](http://debreate.sourceforge.net) but [`lintian`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/#AEN124) evaluates the package and reports a lot of errors and warnings within the object files from the JRE I bundled in the package.

I would like to know how to package a `jar`, Java runtime 8, other files(*.jasper, *.css, *.png, ..) in one debian package and ship it?

Comment: What did you try so far? A simple Google search shows promising results.

Comment: Don't package Java RT 8, make a requirement out of it, unless it isn't available. A quick google search gives loads of hits. I liked http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/ which refers to http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/ 
That should provide enough information to start with

Comment: i tried to package it using [ Debreate ] (http://debreate.sourceforge.net/) but Lintain, evaluates the package and finds so many errors and warnings with in the object files from the JRE i bundled in the package, so i wondered if there is a all in one tutorial on specifically java based application with JRE bundled in it. 

Because i tried to put all the pieces together myself.

Comment: Hi, your question came to me in a review queue for Help and Improvement. I've edited in what you've done already from your comments, fixed a few typos.  Also changed "linux" to "Linux (Debian)", because `.deb` is relevant to Debain only. Mainly, though, for even better help - you should put in some sample errors / warnings from lintian and ask a specific question about how to fix, otherwise this might get closed as "Off Topic - asking for off-site recommendation". Good luck!